# SSRS Correct XY scatter graph for text questions

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I am developing an SSRS 2008 R2 RDL file.  Currently I am trying to get a table in this RDL to list out each question and answer in Scantron fashion.  All 8 questions have the same possible 4 values.  I am using the XY Scatter Plot chart in SSRS.  Here is what my design tab looks like:
[image: design tab]

But this is not correct because here is what the preview tab looks like:
[image: preview tab]

And I followed the second method from URL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seanboon/archive/2009/06/03/working-with-xy-scatter-charts-in-reporting-services-2008.aspx

So how can I fix this so that each question appears on a separate row?

This is the output from my sproc:

```
question                    answer
Housing Has                     resources
Family/Social Support           Has resources
Community/Individual Support    Resource not available
Financial                   Unknown
Healthcare                  Unknown
Transportation                  Needs assistance to obtain
Educational                 Resource not available
Vocational                  Needs assistance to obtain
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your issue well or not but can you please ** Insert a List ** in the **RDL** file and then put your ** Graphh inside the list **, then Add a group to list and check ifyou have a seperate graph for each question or not. **let me know** what's happen or whether I fully understand your issue or not